# Multiple wheres in Laravel join

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have:

```
$buyingNet = DB::table('parts_enquiries_buying AS PEB')
            ->select(DB::raw('SUM((PEB.quantity*PEB.net)/IF(ISNULL(currencyRate), rate, currencyRate)) AS total'))
            ->join('currencies_rates AS CR', function ($q) {
                $q->on('CR.id', '=', 'PEB.currencyId')
                    //->where(DB::raw('YEAR(CR.date)'), '=', date('Y'))
                    ->where(DB::raw('MONTH(CR.date)'), '=', date('m'));
            })
            ->leftJoin('jobs', 'jobs.enquiryId', '=', 'PEB.enquiryId')
            ->leftJoin('invoices_out AS IO', 'IO.jobId', '=', 'jobs.id')
            ->where('PEB.enquiryId', $enquiryId)
            ->first()->total;
```

If I uncomment the where that matches the year I get null returned, but all the rows that should be there are there.

Is my syntax correct? It should translate as:

```
... YEAR(CR.date) = ? AND MONTH(CR.date) =? ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue here is that Query builder doesn't understand your `DB::raw` statement within the `->where` clause.

You should do as folllows:

```
->whereRaw("YEAR(CR.date) = '". date('Y')."'")
->whereRaw("MONTH(CR.date) = '". date('n')."'")
```

for the month clause you need to use `n` instead of `m` since MySQL `MONTH` returns a single digit for months below 10.